# Setting wallpaper with Win API

Tags: windows, winapi, wallpaper

I want to programmatically set a wallpaper. Here's the only solution I've found so far:

```
SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 1, (void*)wallpaperImageFilePath.utf16(), SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

My question is: how to tell Windows I want the wallpaper image centered (not resized)? The solution above always sets the image in stretch mode. According to MSDN, there are no flags to accompany `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no API function for setting the wallpaper orientation.  You have to go to the Registry directly instead, specifically the `"WallpaperStyle"` and `"TileWallpaper"` values of the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` key.  See this article for an example:

[Set the desktop wallpaper (CppSetDesktopWallpaper)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppSetDesktopWallpaper-eb969505)

Answer (score 13):

As of Windows 8 there is now a published interface for setting the desktop background. Specifically the `IDesktopBackground::SetWallpaper` method. [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706962.aspx)

The interface also has several methods for getting and setting the configuration of the slideshow, and obtaining the required monitor device paths.