# Changing Background-Image on Windows

Tags: c++, windows

How can I change **background-image** of desktop with C++ on Windows?

Or Is there any command for this process to using at cmd?

Comment: Background-image of what?

Comment: desktop's wallpaper

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186400/setting-wallpaper-with-win-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the background image of the desktop with  `SystemParametersInfo()`.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

int main() {

    int return_value = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, L"d:/flower1.jpg", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);

    return 0;
}
```